# SSRS group by datediff for Pie chart

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder

I'm just starting learning SSRS so forgive me if this is a simple question but I can't seem to find an appropriate answer... I have a dataset with service tickets, query something like this:

```
SELECT service_tickets, Company_id, Urgency, Date_Entered_UTC, Date_Closed_UTC
   CASE when servicetype = '' then 'Other' else servicetype end as ServiceType, 
   CASE when servicesubtype = '' then 'Other' else servicesubtype end as ServiceSubType, 
FROM v_Service
WHERE Hours_Actual >0
```

I am wanting to group the results of this by quarter using the `date_entered` field for a Pie chart (and ultimately display it as a percentage of the total i.e. 40% of all tickets logged in Q1, 20% of all tickets logged in Q2 etc but I'll worry about that later). The query below gives me the correct count:

```
SELECT count(service_tickets) as Tickets 
FROM v_service 
   WHERE ...
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(qq, date_entered, getdate())
```

However, as I'm using the dataset for several graphs in the same report I need to keep all the fields as they are in the first query. So I'm trying to figure out how to tell SSRS to group the results from the first dataset to give me the results like from the second query. In essence, how can I translate the `group by datediff` into a pie chart using the original dataset?

Comment: Not an answer but are you sure you want to group by datediff() and not datepart()? The first will count how many quarters away from the current date, the second will give you the actual quarter...

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that the easiest way to do this was insert the chart as a subreport, thereby creating it's own dataset and not being restricted by the dataset used in the existing charts.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to group on an SSRS expression. In this case:

```
=DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Quarter, Fields!date_entered.Value, Now())
```

However, it might be cleaner to add that expression as a calculated column in your data set. Open the data set properties, select "Fields" on the left, and click "Add"..."Calculated column". Then name your field and add the expression in the source box.

But you should be able to add it as an additional column in your SQL query without affecting the other items on the report. Just add `DATEDIFF(qq, date_entered, GETDATE()) AS Quarters_since_entered` to the SELECT clause.